# Phonegap app works fine on iPhone crashes on iPad?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

My phonegap / jquery mobile app works fine when installed on an iPhone 4s running 6.1.2 but doesnt work at all on a 4th gen iPad (running the same 6.1.2). All I get is an unstyled first page, no JS functionality or JQM styling.

Pulling my hair out - anyone know of any potential causes?

The xCode project is straight from the phonegap script and hasn't been tampered with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a strange one, managed to solve this by rebuilding the xCode project from the phonegap script. Hope this helps someone.